# NgRok forwarding to EC2 instance which is using nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, ngrok

I have an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 22. Initially, I ran Nginx to route traffic from the public IP address, let's say it is 123.456.789.101, for example, of the EC2. Then I logged into my instance and started a FastAPI server that ran on localhost:8000. The script below routes the traffic from 123.456.789.101 to the server running in EC2.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 123.456.789.101;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Now when i open the browser and type *123.456.789.101/some/api/endpoint* it works fine.

The next thing I did was install ngrok to route traffic from the ngrok generated address (xxx.ngrok.io) to 123.456.789.101 by using this command in the ngrok terminal:

```
ngrok http 123.456.789.101:80
```

and it gives me this output:

```
Session Status                online                                                                                   
Version                       3.1.1                                                                                     
Region                        Europe (eu)                                                                               
Latency                       57ms                                                                                      
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040   
Forwarding                    https://xxx.ngrok.io -> http://123.456.789.101:80                                                                                                                                                 
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                                       1       0       0.00    0.00    75.76   75.76
```

The issue here is that it clearly states that whatever traffic arrives to *https://xxx.ngrok.io* will be forwarded to *http://123.456.789.101:80* which is the public IP address of my EC2 instance.

And earlier I tested *123.456.789.101/some/api/endpoint* in the browser and it works fine, but when I type *https://xxx.ngrok.io/the/same/endpoint* it does not work and simply gives me a 404 page that looks like this:
[image: 404 picture]

So I was wondering, what could be the issue here. Even though it states that it is forwarding the traffic to the EC2 instance, nothing is actually arriving.

Thank you

Comment: if your application is running on localhost:8000 inside the ec2, why not use `ngrok http 8000` . You will get your intended result I suppose. If not this,  why use ngrok when you already have a public IP?